# Why doesn't Ubuntu provide Firefox ESR in its repositories?

Tags: firefox, official-repositories

There is no "firefox-esr" package when I try to search for it using `apt-cache search firefox-esr`. This is surprising because Debian stable has a [firefox-esr](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firefox-esr) package. Is there a reason why Ubuntu does not include the firefox-esr package in its official repositories?

Comment: You mention Debian... if you recall back Debian provide `iceweasel` for along time being unable to provide `firefox` at all.  Firefox is now a *snap* as that's what Mozilla wants, just as when Mozilla/Debian relationship improved, Debian was able to replace `iceweasel` with `firefox` itself.  Ubuntu provides the `firefox` package that Mozilla wants them too, which for future releases is now a *snap* package...

Comment: I thought that the Mozilla Team supported the deb package from the `ppa`.  Just look at the answer about adding Mozilla ppa. Just remove the snap from Ubuntu, then install from the ppa.

Answer (score 13):

This question can really only be answered by a person within Canonical who is authorised to speak on the matter, and it's unlikely such a person will stop by to provide an answer that meets expectations. That said, you can install the ESR package by first [uninstalling the Snap version of Firefox](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04), adding [Mozilla's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), and installing the package yourself.

Putting the above steps all together, you can do something like this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Remove the Firefox Snap:

   ```
   sudo snap remove firefox
   ```
2. Add Mozilla's PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
   ```
3. Set the Mozilla PPA as a preferred source:

   ```
   echo '
   Package: *
   Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
   Pin-Priority: 1001
   ' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
   ```
4. Install the ESR:

   ```
   sudo apt install firefox-esr
   ```

This should give you Firefox ESR 91.9.0.

Comment: @wha7ever literally the first step of this answer is to remove the Firefox snap

Comment: @Esther Duh. Indeed. I was tired yesterday. I though the first step was to add snap. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

**The Snap does offer ESR**

First, let's talk about how to get ESR directly from Mozilla using the snap (Ubuntu 22.04 and later).

Let's look at the firefox snap:

```
$ snap info firefox
name:      firefox
...
channels:
  latest/stable:    99.0.1-1    2022-04-13 (1232) 163MB -
  latest/candidate: 100.0-2     2022-05-02 (1300) 168MB -
  latest/beta:      101.0b1-1   2022-05-03 (1306) 169MB -
  latest/edge:      102.0a1     2022-05-04 (1310) 180MB -
  esr/stable:       91.8.0esr-1 2022-04-05 (1184) 161MB -
  esr/candidate:    91.9.0esr-1 2022-04-27 (1284) 161MB -
  esr/beta:         ↑                                   
  esr/edge:         ↑
```

So installing Firefox ESR is as simple as

`$ snap install firefox --channel=esr/stable`

There is no Step 2. That was it.

---

Now let's step back answer why it's not available *in the Ubuntu Repositories* as a deb (Ubuntu 21.10 and earlier). It's available as a PPA, of course.

It comes down to resources: Building and testing each new update of Firefox takes hours of *somebody's* time.

- No community volunteers have stepped forward to take on that continuous effort of maintaining the deb package (Universe repository). It's more than building -- it's testing, it's triaging and upstreaming bugs, and it's answering support questions about the deb.
- The Ubuntu Desktop Team isn't willing to pay their engineers to do the job for a package that won't be part of a stock install (Main repository).
- In the PPA, somebody else (Mozilla in this case) is doing the building, but YOU are doing the testing and discovering the rough edges and filing the bug reports and answering your own support questions.

Comment: On Pop_OS 22.04 I needed to remove the existing Firefox to help me launch the right one. `sudo apt remove firefox` `sudo snap install firefox --channel=esr/stable` then launch Firefox from the command line with `firefox -allow-downgrade` to keep using my user profile (be sure to backup first; I use deja-dup).